# Installed VS Code via snap, now it won't open

Tags: snap, visual-studio-code

**I have looked all over the internet for how to fix this**

Installed code via

`sudo snap install code --classic`

Now when I search for code from the start button menu it shows up, but when I click it nothing happens.

also my `code` command in terminal gives me this error:

`/ has 'other' write 40777`

I'm new to Ubuntu, and have no idea what is wrong,

Thanks for your time

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how, but I fixed it with `sudo chmod 755 /`

Comment: @HenryvanMegen I just spun an ubuntu 20.04 VM and a 22.04 VM.  In both cases, the `/` folder on that folder directly has the permissions `755` on it, with owner of `root` and group of `root`.  The answer as written simply restores this permission on the `/` folder, which is what a default install already has.  Because this is not a `chmod -R` this is not a really *dangerous* command to execute as this just resets the default permissions on `/` and only on `/` to what they were on a default install.

Comment: I did this on the machine that had this problem, but it didn't help (`xubuntu 20.04` with default kernel `5.13.0-40-generic` running vscode version `1.67.1`). Only when I remove `~/.vscode/` I can get it to start once, after that single succesful startup (and with the `~/.vscode/` directory recreated), it won't start up anymore.